# ActionController::UnknownFormat in rails API fetch request with JavaScript Front-end

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, json

SPA html/JavaScript Rails app with a json API BackEnd to serve up data to the Front. The index page is displayed and built entirely with JS in a javascript_pack_tag. I then both call my own api for json data saved in PG and then to a third party API openweathermap. Everything was working just as I wanted then I attempted to store my openweathermap API key with the gon gem. I was able to do this. However it broke my app. I then undid all of the gon gem stuff and it the app is still broken.

**Error**
**terminal**

```
#ubuntu terminal
ActionController::UnknownFormat (CitiesController#index is missing a template 
for this request format and variant.

request.formats: ["application/json"]
request.variant: []):
```

**console**

```
#chrome console
class_mode.js:238 GET http://localhost:3000/cities.json 406 (Not Acceptable)
fetchCityData @ class_mode.js:238
(anonymous) @ class_mode.js:9
localhost/:1 Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
```

```
#class_mode.js 
line 238> return fetch(BASE_URL).then(res => res.json()).then(function (json) {
```

From these errors I have traced this back to my controller action returning HTML instead of JSON. Specifically the **<** indicates html returning in the controller.

**Latest attempt to fix in controller**

```
 def index 
   @all = City.all_in_json  
   respond_to do |format|
      format.html { render :index }
      format.json { @all }
    end
   end
```

I also moved the json logic into the City model as such

```
def  self.all_in_json 
         @cities = self.all
              @returnValue = @cities.map do |city|  
             if city[:name] === nil 
                city[:name] = city.to_name 
                city.save! 
                city
             else
                city
              end  
              end  
            @returnValue.to_json 

    end
```

Again this app was working perfectly. I have spend a full day of debugging now and am turning to StackOverflow.
I have attempted to create distinct routes to call my fetch() request to for the retrieval of all the records of the City table/ tried respond_to.

Answer (score 1):

Your controller action does not say what to render, it simply calls the @all variable. Assuming you're correctly asigning @all to a json string, then try changing your controller method it:

```
 def index 
   @all = City.all_in_json  
   respond_to do |format|
      format.html { render :index }
      format.json { render json: @all, status: 200, message: 'bla' }
   end
 end
```

Status and message are optional

Comment: Update. Mark was correct and his response is the correct answer. The code that worked is as follows 

```def index 
   @all = City.all_in_json  
   @alll = City.all
   respond_to do |format|
      format.html { render :index }
      
      format.json { render json: @alll }
    end
   end  
``` 
This will render the all for json when I make the fetch('cities.json') and the index.html.erb page upon loading with root to 'cities#index'.